# How to use NHibernate sessions in WinForms where the 'conversation' is very long

Tags: winforms, session, nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate. For much of of my Winforms app, I can use the 'session per use-case' model. The app helps a manager calculate commission data for salespeople, and there are 3 main grids in 3 tabs with financial data. Those grids stay open the entire time the application is open, like Excel, and then when he quits he can save his data, which saves the grids. There are also a few operations that will save his data before continuing.

How should my NHibernate sessions work for these 3 grids that just stay open? The data on the 3 grids is logically separate and 'flows down' so if the user changes something on one, he can use a button to push the changes through to the other grids.

For these main grids, I think I should a session for each grid, and just leave them open until he saves. So far this is working not too badly, but I don't want to cause future problems. I'm about to start work on grid three, and it's a good time to change things around.

Edit: On reflection, a session for each grid seems like a mistake. If I do that, then in my service layer I need to know which session went with which data and it feels like it would make a mess. Really, all 3 grids are in the same 'conversation', even though it's a long one.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid conversational usage of Session unless you have a good reason. Instead far better and simpler idea is **unit of work pattern**. That is, open and dispose the request for each single operation. e.g You want to save something, open , commit, dispose. Also long running session can be memory hog since they start the track the objects for long time.